# Disable 'recommends' from within package control file

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm packaging an internal app for our company's repo which has [libvips42](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/libvips42) as a dependancy.

This package recommends [nip2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/nip2), which in turn recommends iceweasel. This has the undesired side-effect of installing a large number of unwanted packages (including libx11 on servers that don't run a GUI).

Rather than having to update apt.conf on each client to include `APT::Install-Recommends "0"` is there any way of setting it within the control file of the package I am building so recommended packages of dependencies are not installed in this one instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an exact answer to my question, but I worked around the issue using

`apt-get -o apt::install-recommends=false <packagename>`

in the Anisble playbook used to provision our servers.